# Associating nodes to a user

Tags: nodes, users, views

I'm trying to create a Parish website. I have a list of parish members with email ids and without email ids. I've imported the users with email addresses as users, and the rest as nodes. Members that belongs to same family shares a common family code, and when a user log in I want to have a view of all family members and their necessary details (i.e. address,phone no,etc).

But the problem I have is that some users are created using user import and some (people without email) are created as nodes.

So how can I display all the members with same family code in a single view? How to relate a user with another user/nodes.

Is it with contextual filters/relationships? I tried with it but couldn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must make all users users and not nodes. Somebody I know recently had an issue where users didn't have email addresses. His solution was to create fake email ids for those users since having an email id is mandatory for an account on a Drupal site.
Once you have everyone as users, I think you can add relationships between users using this module - [User Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships) and hence easily show related users in views.